# How to seek media player to a specific frame position?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, frame

This is the  method that i am using is 
`mediaPlayer.seekTo.`

This is to move current position:

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+4);
```

This go to the frame number 0:

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(4);
```

Does not matters the number always go to the frame number 0.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you provide to `seekTo(long)` is given in milliseconds, not in frames.
When the time in milliseconds is not exactly on a sync frame, it will go to the previous sync frame in the video.
In your case (4ms into the video), this is apparently frame 0.

Also see [`MediaPlayer.seekTo(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) and [`SEEK_PREVIOUS_SYNC`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#SEEK_PREVIOUS_SYNC)

Edit: With API `seekTo(long, int)` was introduced, which enables you to change this behavior (c.f. [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(long,%20int)))